# GLSL: 2D space transform matrix of Custom Shader

Tags: python, scripting, glsl

Here is a template of build-in shader to draw a 2D Rectangle in viewport and that is good.

[image]

```
import bpy, gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

vertices = (
    (100, 100), (300, 100),
    (100, 200), (300, 200))

indices = (
    (0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3))

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"pos": vertices}, indices=indices)

def draw():
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("color", (0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0))
    batch.draw(shader)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

Here is my custom shader to draw a gradients rectangle and that is bad when draging the region.

[image]

```
import bpy, gpu
from mathutils import Matrix
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from bgl import glEnable, GL_BLEND

vertex_shader = '''
    uniform mat4 winMat;

    in vec2 position;
    out vec2 pos;

    void main(){
        pos = position;
        gl_Position = winMat * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
'''

fragment_shader = '''
    uniform vec4 color;
    uniform vec4 LRBT;
    uniform float d;

    in vec2 pos;
    out vec4 FragColor;

    float c;

    void main()
    {
        if (pos[0] < LRBT[0] + d){
            c = color[3]/d *(pos[0] - LRBT[0]);
        }else{
            if (pos[0] > LRBT[1] - d){
                c = color[3]/d *(LRBT[1] - pos[0]);
            }else{
                c = color[3];
            }
        }
        if (pos[1] < LRBT[2] + d){
            c *= color[3]/d * (pos[1] - LRBT[2]);
        }else{
            if (pos[1] > LRBT[3] - d){
                c *= color[3]/d *(LRBT[3] - pos[1]); 
            }
        }

        FragColor = vec4(color[0], color[1], color[2], c);
    }
'''

vertices = (
    (100, 100), (300, 100),
    (100, 200), (300, 200))

indices = (
    (0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3))

viewMat = Matrix((
    (0.0009, 0.0000, 0.0000, -0.7200),
    (0.0000, 0.0009, 0.0000, -0.4674),
    (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, -1.0000),
    (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0100,  4.2783)
))

shader = gpu.types.GPUShader(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)
batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"position": vertices}, indices=indices)
shader.uniform_float("color", (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0))
v = vertices
shader.uniform_float("LRBT", (v[0][0], v[1][0], v[0][1], v[2][1]))
shader.uniform_float("d", 30)

def draw():
    glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("winMat", bpy.context.region_data.window_matrix @ viewMat)
    batch.draw(shader)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

It can maintain the size and location when pan/rotate the viewport. But it is invalid when I drag to add more viewport in the workspace. You can see the size and region position of the rectangle are changing. I don't want the rectangle to change size and position when I drag or enlarge the viewport (of the right hand side in the image)

[image]

##### So the question: What is the correct transform matrix of the shader? or a method to fix this problem just like the build-in shader.

Comment: So instead of looking like this: [BAD](https://i.imgur.com/SuF2XYK.gif) you want it to look like this? [GOOD](https://imgur.com/wcWXmlU) Your 2nd code posted seems irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I provided additional information to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw a rectangle with the built-in shaders, they all use *ModelViewProjectionMatrix*.

The [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.shader.html#gpu.shader.from_builtin) states:

> *"...They all read the uniform mat4 ModelViewProjectionMatrix, which can be edited by the gpu.matrix module."*

Therefore, it might be a solution to use the same matrix for your custom rectangle.

Replace the line:

```py
shader.uniform_float("winMat", bpy.context.region_data.window_matrix @ viewMat)
```

with the following:

```py
shader.uniform_float("winMat", gpu.matrix.get_projection_matrix())
```

With this you draw a rectangle with the gradient you defined before.

Comment: Perfect, the problem is solved.