# Dashed Lines GLSL Even Sizing

Tags: python, opengl

I'm working on a dashed line shader in a Blender add-on and my aim is to get all lines, regardless of length, to have the same sized dashes and dash spacing.

GPU shaders are relatively new to me so I may be approaching this incorrectly. My code is below for the shader (using a slightly edited version of the example code from the Blender docs).

I pass u_Scale and u_Spacing to the shader which corresponds to the dash size and spacing between the dashes. lineLength is a 2D array [0, <line_length>]. If I understand correctly the shader will gradually move along the length of the line, calculating the sine of the current position * u_scale and discarding as the step values reach 1, so causing the spaces but please correct me if I'm wrong on that.

```
def return_shader_3d() -> GPUShader:
vertex_shader = """
        uniform mat4 u_ViewProjectionMatrix;

        in vec3 position;
        in float lineLength;

        out float v_LineLength;

        void main()
        {
            v_LineLength = lineLength;
            gl_Position = u_ViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
        }
    """

fragment_shader = """
    uniform float u_Scale;
    uniform float u_Spacing;
    uniform vec4 u_col;

    in float v_LineLength;
    out vec4 fragColor;

    void main()
    {
        if (step(sin(v_LineLength * u_Scale), u_Spacing) == 1) discard;
        fragColor = u_col;
    }
"""
return GPUShader(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)
```

The image shows the output for the various line sizes at 4000, 2000, 1000, 500, 250, 100mm with **u_scale=100** and **u_spacing = 0.1**

[image: Output for various line sizes 4000, 2000, 1000, 500, 250, 100mm]

I created some property sliders for u_scale and u_spacing but I can't seem to find a formula for calculating the correct properties for each length of a line while maintaining a consistent spacing and dash size across all lines.

I'm wondering if using step and sin is the correct way to handle this and if not, is there a better way to approach the problem?

Ideally, I'll be able to use the viewport zoom distance to scale both values whilst zooming (to keep a consistent size regardless of zoom) but I think the above problem needs to be solved first.

The GPU shading documentation for Blender is quite limited so if anyone knows of a good learning resource that would be really useful.

**UPDATE**

I've made some progress on this but some issues remain and certainly some strange behaviour with the shader.

Using the below fragment shader code I can get evenly spaced dashes:

```
fragment_shader = """
    uniform float u_DashSize;
    uniform float u_Spacing;

    in float v_LineLength;
    out vec4 fragColor;

    void main()
    {   
        float val = mod(v_LineLength, u_DashSize);
        if (val < u_Spacing)
            val = 1.0;
        else
            val = 0.0;

        //if (val == 0.0) discard;

        fragColor = vec4(0.0, val, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
"""
```

[image: Dashed lines even]

However, if I uncomment the if statement to discard, I get solid lines with no gaps. I could set the alpha value in the fragColor to 0.0 instead of discarding but unless the pixel is over something (not the background) Blender still draws a black line.

This is the full shader code (my dash size is 0.2 and spacing is 0.14):

```
def return_shader_3d() -> GPUShader:
vertex_shader = """
        uniform mat4 u_ViewProjectionMatrix;

        in vec3 position;
        in float lineLength;

        out float v_LineLength;

        void main()
        {
            v_LineLength = lineLength;
            gl_Position = u_ViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
        }
    """



fragment_shader = """
    uniform float u_DashSize;
    uniform float u_Spacing;

    in float v_LineLength;
    out vec4 fragColor;

    void main()
    {   
        float val = mod(v_LineLength, u_DashSize);
        if (val < u_Spacing)
            val = 1.0;
        else
            val = 0.0;

        //if (val == 0.0) discard;
        fragColor = vec4(0.0, val, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
"""
return GPUShader(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)
```

And here's the calling code from the bacth_draw function:

```
    line_lengths = [0]
    for a, b in zip(coords[:-1], coords[1:]):
        line_lengths.append(line_lengths[-1] + (a - b).length)

    # shader = gpu.types.GPUShader(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)
    shader = return_shader_3d()
    batch = batch_for_shader(
        shader, line_style, {"position": coords, "lineLength": line_lengths}
    )

    shader.bind()
    matrix = bpy.context.region_data.perspective_matrix
    shader.uniform_float("u_ViewProjectionMatrix", matrix)
    shader.uniform_float("u_DashSize", u_scale)
    shader.uniform_float("u_Spacing", u_spacing)
```

Comment: I once did a drop shadow for UI interface, here is the example: 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263497/glsl-2d-space-transform-matrix-of-custom-shader

Comment: i get error with `bpy.types.GPUShader` my blender 3.1 cannot detect even though i have `import gpu` statement.

Comment: @XY Thanks for posting. I found this a while back and was useful for another add-on I'm working on.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie you need to use: from gpu.types import GPUShader

Comment: yeah i tried that but it didnt work for me. which blender are u using? i think its only for 3.2. im on 3.1

Comment: It's been the same since around 2.9 I think.

Comment: oh wait i did `from bpy.types` instead of `from gpu.types`

Comment: @Dan i can't seem to get your shader code to run, can you paste the entire script?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie just added it to the bottom of the main question.

Comment: hmmm it's not complete.. `coords` not defined. can u paste a functional block of script that works? xd, don't separate the script. just as 1 script, also imports are missing :)